# How to stop postgres stats collector properly?

Tags: postgresql

I tried to profile plpgsql functions.
And I use pg_stat_statements to do that.
I can do profile, but after that I can not restart postgresql.

Result of `ps -aux` is below

```
postgres 22129  0.0  0.1 1276896 37276 ?       Ss   07:13   0:00 postgres: dbname: checkpointer process   
postgres 22134  0.0  0.0 178008  4360 ?        Ss   07:13   0:00 postgres: dbname: stats collector process   
postgres 23030 18.5  0.9 1436048 316336 ?      Ss   07:17   4:53 postgres: dbname: postgres sakura 127.0.0.1(56496) idle waiting for D1E/CEA4D9C8
```

I think stats process may be lock the server to restart.
I think it's locking to stop server, because after that I have to wait long time to only shutdown the PC. May be shutdown process is waiting until stats process stop.

Is there any way to stop stats process properly?
Or, the way to force top stats process?

I tried `kill -9`, but it does not help.

Comment: How did you stop PostgreSQL to get it into that state? There is no postmaster running. If a process is blocked (say, on I/O) so that you cannot kill it, you'll have to restart.

Comment: I just do service postgresql restart. So I have to restart my pc? How can I stop properly？

Comment: That depends on a lot of factors that you didn't disclose (see my questions).

Comment: Sorry for my poor reply. I thought I stopped every query. But I found query that disclosed that QGIS use. After close QGIS, I can restart postgresql.

Comment: I could stop service like this.
/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl -D /path/to/database stop -m i

Comment: So you crashed the database. `-m f` didn't work?

Comment: No. -m f didn't work.

Comment: Look at the log file. Use `gdb` to attach to the hanging process and generate a stack trace.